# How to calculate the tax bracket needed to achieve a given budget income and tax rate

Tags: algorithm, math

I have and assignment where I have a database of incomes of citizens of a country (one record - income of a single citizen). A tax is to be imposed on the citizens with a given tax rate of r (for instance 30%) on incomes over a certain level (just like normal tax brackets work). The government budget wants to earn a given tax income from this tax (let's say x). What is the tax bracket? I'm writing this in R, but I need help with the algorithm, not the coding itself.
To make it more clear: if citizen number 2342 earns an income i, that is higher than the bracket y, than he pays (i-y)*r. If another citizen earns less than y, he doesn't pay any tax. I have let's say 10000 i's of 10000 citizens. All the taxes payed by all the citizens need to sum to a given value x and the r rate is given. How to calculate the y bracket?
Thanks for all the help

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable, and is likely a violation of your school's academic honesty policies.

Comment: This is a totally valid algorithmic problem that I've been trying to solve for several days. I'm not asking anyone to write the code for me and it's not homework. I'm asking for general direction in how to approach this. I know why my previous code did not do what I needed it to do

Comment: The principle is still the same as with homework.
If this is not a coding problem, then it shouldn't be tagged with languages.
As given, you're asking us to derive your math solution for you.

Comment: In particular, the problem is under-constrained.  As given, there are infinite solutions; you have one extra degree of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

You have one more degree of freedom than will permit a unique solution.  Let's consider the degenerate case of a single taxpayer, making 10,000 monetary units.  Let's say that you need to collect 1,000 in taxes.  Your equation is simply

```
1000 = (10000 - y) * r
```

You're asking for the algorithm to solve this for r.  As you can see, this will result in a simple linear equation.

Now look at the problem with two taxpayers, making 10,000 and 9,000.  Now you have:

```
1000 = (10000 - y) * r + max(0, (9000 - y)) * r
```

You still have a *piecewise* linear function, but with a change in slope at y = 9000, where the second taxpayer begins to contribute.  Wherever you set that bracket, there is a value for `r` that yields the desired total income.

Answer (score 0):

It's a minimization problem.

1. Pick a guess for y
2. Calculate how much tax will be collected
3. Check if collected tax is within a given tolerance of the desired tax. If that is the case then stop.
4. If the collected tax is too low, you need to decrease y, otherwise increase y. Adjust y accordingly and repeat from 2.